# Disable Tabular Menu in Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tabs, semantic-ui

I am using Tabular Menus of Semantic UI in javascript. 
I cannot find any way of disabling these items. I tried putting class 'item disabled' but this is not working for me.

here's how i'm defining these items:

```
 <div class="item" data-tab="patient"><i class="user circular orange icon trn" data-trn-key=""></i>Patient</div>
```

Its still getting CLICKED and Active even after i put 'item disabled' class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the icon look disabled , then add `.disabled` class to `i` element :

```
<i class="user circular orange icon trn disabled" data-trn-key=""></i>
```

To disable the `click` event add this to your js *(jQuery)*:

```
$('#clickElement').off('click');
```

[[Demo]](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/jYWoQQ)